# Amazon AWS Elasticsearch installing plugins and files

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

is it somehow possible to install plugins on Amazon Elasticsearch service ? I would need for example lemmagen plugin.

Next thing, including custom file like for stopwords, in analyzer, stopwords_path. I have looked into documentation but found nothing about this custom things.

Thanks much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AWS ES only supports and manages [these](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-plugins.html) plugins that is prepackaged into AWS ES. You cannot install other custom plugins.

You also cannot add stop words files to AWS ES and refer those paths. Here is a discussion forum [link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=679800).

In this case you can use the Elastic Search API method to add stopwords to your index. Here is an [example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html#analysis-stop-tokenfilter) from Elastic Search documentation.

Comment: So still no solution, i have quite large array of stopwords for example, not so handy to specify it in array. Anyway thanks, good link :)